# Any plugin installation failed - could not copy file error

Tags: wordpress, plugins

everytime I install a new plugin for wordpress it says Could not copy file and the files address. Does anybody know why this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue but in my case I was updating using FTP.

I fixed it by setting the hostname to "localhost" instead of using the IP.

This is because there was a loop happening and making the file upload fail and that's logged in the /var/log/vsftpd.log

Answer (score 3):

Check file premissions and (**important!**) file owner or group. If you use apache server group must be www-data (default).  This can be a [solution](https://wordpress.2bearstudio.com/wordpress-update-installation-failed-could-not-copy-files/)

Comment: File Permissions were the problem. Thanks very much!

Comment: giving the ownership of the files to www-data user is very insecure. other websites on the server are run by the same user. a script in another website running on the same server can write on your files.

Comment: @mustafa thanks for that. Could you also offer a solutions though?