# Wordpress WooCommerce plugin Installation failed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

when im trying to install the woocommerce plugin
The installation fails and show this error:
Installation failed: Could not copy file. woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/assets/js/blocks/reviews/editor-block.js

Comment: Have you already tried to find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666897/any-plugin-installation-failed-could-not-copy-file-error?

Comment: i did but didn't solve the problem

Comment: Can you describe in detail the steps you have taken so far? Forward in which environment are you working?